# Find ImT, KerT - Linear Map - Solution Verification

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Regarding:

$T:\mathbb{R}_3[x] \to \mathbb{R}_3[x], T(a_0 + a_1x + 2a_2x^2) = a_1 + 2a_2x$ - Find ImT and KerT:

Here is my attempt:

ImT=span$(T(1), T(x), T(x^2))$

$T(1)=T(0x^2+0x+1*1) = 0$

$T(x)=T(0x^2+1x+0*1) = 1$

$T(x^2)=T(1x^2+0x+0*1) = 2x$

So $ImT =$ span$(0,1,2x)=$ span$(1,2x)=$ span$(1,x)$

$KerT=[p(x)\in\mathbb{R}_3[x] : T(p(x))=0]$

$p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$ so $T(p(x))=a_1+2a_2x=0$ so $a_1=a_2=0$, so $p(x)=a_0 \to KerT =span(1)$

Is that correct?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Provided that $T(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2)=a_1+2a_2x$.

Comment: @Berci Thank you! Can you confirm that span(1,2x) == span(1,x)? This one I would like to verify twice :)

Comment: Yes, I can confirm. You can easily verify, btw, that both $1$ and $x$ are in ${\rm span}(1,2x)$ and $1$ and $2x$ are in ${\rm span}(1,x)$.

Comment: @Berci Great. Thank you so much for your help!